# Loading a user's configuration file into symfony console

Tags: console, yaml, configuration-files, symfony4

I have a Symfony console application and I'd like to let the user set some configuration in a yaml file.

I have looked through the Symfony documentation but the documentation appears to be all about application, service or bundle configuration.

Is there a Symfony 4 package/class which I can use to provide a path to a yaml file and read its contents?